# Post-increment in a while loop

Tags: c, pointers, post-increment

The following code confused me a bit:

```
char * strcpy(char * p, const char * q) {
  while (*p++=*q++);
  //return
}
```

This is a stripped down implementation of `strcpy` function. From this code, we see that pointer `p` and `q` are incremented then dereferenced and `q` is assigned to `p` until the `\0` char has been reached.

I would like someone to explain the first iteration of the while loop.

Comment: Your definitions of post/pre seem to be backwards. Post = after, Pre = before. The post-increment here shows that the first character will be copied, then the pointer will be incremented.

Comment: Why the C++ tag (and title) ? This is a C library function.

Comment: Looks like perfectly valid C++ code to me, @Paul. So why *not* the C++ tag?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the pointer assignment in strcpy work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780093/how-does-the-pointer-assignment-in-strcpy-work)

Comment: @Rob: well it's perfectly valid **Objective-C** code too - perhaps it should be tagged as `Objective-C` then ?

Comment: @Davita: not quite - it still says "C++" in the title.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because the `++` is after the variables, they aren't incremented until *after* the expression is evaluated. That's why it's the post-increment operator; the pre-increment is prefixed (`++p`).  `*++p` would write to the second spot, `*p++` writes to the first.

Answer (score 2):

`p++` is post-incrementing the pointer `p`. So the current value of `p` is operated upon by the deference operator `*` before `p` is incremented.

Your reasoning would've been correct if the `while` loop was written as follows:

```
while (*++p=*++q);
```

In this case the increment would happen before dereferencing.

Answer (score 2):

No, the increment happens after the assignment.

If it were `*(++p)`, the pointer `p` would be incremented and after that assigned.

Answer (score 2):

The expressions `x++` and `++x` have both a *result* (value) and a *side effect*.

The *result* of the expression `x++` is the current value of `x`.  The *side effect* is that the contents of `x` are incremented by 1.

The *result* of the expression `++x` is the current value of `x` plus 1.  The *side effect* is the same as above.

Note that the side effect doesn't have to be applied immediately after the expression is evaluated; it only has to be applied before the next sequence point.  For example, given the code

```
x = 1;
y = 2;
z = ++x + y++;
```

there's no guarantee that the contents of `x` will be modified before the expression `y++` is evaluated, or even before the result of `++x + y++` is assigned to `z` (neither the `=` nor `+` operators introduce a sequence point).  The *expression* `++x` evaluates to 2, but it's possible that the variable `x` may not contain the value 2 until after `z` has been assigned.

It's important to remember that the behavior of expressions like `x++ + x++` is *explicitly* undefined by the language standard; there's no (good) way to predict what the result of the expression will be, or what value `x` will contain after it's been evaluated.

Postfix operators have a higher precedence than unary operators, so expressions like `*p++` are parsed as `*(p++)` (i.e., you're applying the `*` operator to the result of the expression `p++`).  Again, the result of the expression `p++` is the current value of `p`, so `while (*p++=*q++);` doesn't skip the first element.

Note that the operand to the autoincrement/decrement operators must be an *lvalue* (essentially, an expression that refers to a memory location such that the memory can be read or modified).  The result of the expression `x++` or `++x` is *not* an lvalue, so you can't write things like `++x++` or `(x++)++` or `++(++x)`.  You *could* write something like `++(*p++)` (`p++` is not an lvalue, but `*p++` is), although that would probably get you slapped by anyone reading your code.

Answer (score 1):

The right hand side of the expression (*q++) will be evaluated prior to *p++, and both will only be incremented after the assignment takes place.

Read the statement right to left and remember post-increment (q++ instead of ++q) happens after everything else in the line is resolved.

```
*q --> dereference q
=  --> assign the value
*p --> to p
```

increment both.

Do this until q p taking q's element = 0 which is when it reaches the null terminator.

Answer (score 1):

> This is a stripped implementation of strcpy function. From this code, we see that pointer p and q are increamented, than dereferenced and q is assigned to p until \0 char has been reached.

It happens the other way around. The value at `*p` is set to `*q`, then both pointers are incremented.

When you have `int foo = bar++` the increment happens after foo has been set. To have it happen first you would do `int foo = ++bar`

Comment: @Marlon, why did you edit my post? you've inverted the meaning, which is incorrect. *p is set to *q, not the other way around unless I'm having a complete brain fart and missing something.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `q++` is q
The value of `++q` is `q+1`

Answer (score 1):

The `while` loop's condition is performing post-increment. Equivalently:

```
while (true) {
    char* old_p = p;
    const char* old_q = q;

    ++p; // or p++;
    ++q; // or q++;

    *old_p = *old_q;
    if (*old_p == '\0')
        break;
}
```

Comment: Not quite true, because your while (*p) is looking at the next character, not the one just copied.